# Handling different pagination schemes within the same book

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm using a [scholarly edition of a verse text](https://books.google.de/books?id=t9E3AQAAMAAJ). The edited text itself is customarily referred to by verse number rather than by page, while the editorial part of the book is paginated normally. To spare me writing "p." or "v." manually every time I refer to either part of the book, I made separate entries for each with the according setting in the `pagination` option where it differs from the default "p." However, this also causes the book to appear twice in my list of references, and `\textcite` produces "Schröder (1895a)" and "Schröder (1895b)," which does not sit well with my advisors.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{schroeder1895,
    editor      = {Edward Schröder},
    title       = {Kaiserchronik eines {R}egensburger Geistlichen},
    maintitle   = {Deutsche Chroniken und andere Geschichtsbücher des Mittelalters},
    volume      = {1},
    publisher   = {Hahn},
    location    = {Hannover},
    date        = {1895},
    series      = {Monumenta Germaniae Historica},
    number      = {1},
}

@inbook{schroeder1895:kc,
    crossref    = {schroeder1895},
    title       = {Kaiserchronik},
    sortkey     = {Schroeder1895b},
    pages       = {79--416},
    pagination  = {verse},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    style=authoryear-comp,
    backend=biber,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite[42]{schroeder1895}, \textcite[1234]{schroeder1895:kc}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of compilation]

My question is, thus, if there is a straightforward way to only print one entry "Schröder (1895)" in both in-text citations and the bibliography, but still automatically get "p. XXX" or "v. XXX":

> Schröder (1895, p. 42), Schröder (1895, v. 1234)
>
> ## References
>
> Schröder, Edward, ed. (1895). *Deutsche Chroniken und andere Geschichtsbücher des Mittelalters*. Vol. 1: *Kaiserchronik eines Regensburger Geistlichen*. Monumenta Germaniae Historica 1. Hannover: Hahn.

I already tried to add `options = {skipbib=true}` to the `@inbook` entry, but that does not have the desired effect and only omits it from the bibliography while keeping the letters on the year. If there's no straightforward way to solve this, I could simply make the default pagination style for the `@book` entry `verse` and manually put `p.~` on the few occasions I refer to the editorial part. I thought I'd still post this question because it strikes me as an interesting problem that I haven't yet found a general solution to.

Comment: I think I have seen a similar question before. At the time I thought about this problem for a wee while and came to the conclusion that while it is a clever idea on first glance using different entries to change the pagination causes probably more issues than it solves. Separate entries are separate entities for all intents and purposes, which has implications for uniqueness, citation tracking and linking.

Comment: I suppose, setting `pagination` to `verse` according to the majority of citation cases, and manually putting "p.~" (or `\nopp~` depending on the citation style) where I refer to the editorial part, is probably the most straightforward way indeed, then, even if it's methodologically a little ugly. I had already expected that someone would say something along your lines—it certainly makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `skipbib=true`, and give it a false year.

Comment: Without further modification (e.g. by defining a shorthand, as I do, but anyway), that would leave the in-text citation as "Schröder (9999: v. 1234)," though.

Comment: You can get a bit closer with `options = {dataonly},` but this breaks down as soon as there is another (bona fide) "Schröder 1895" entry so that we need "Schröder 1895a" and "Schröder 1895b". So this is definitely not a solution.